# Magento Catalog View, Displaying Add To Cart & Pre-Order Buttons (Code So Far Inside)

Tags: php, string, magento, product

Basically what I am trying to achieve is when a simple product has >0 quantity it shows add to cart button. When it has equal to order less than 0 it displays a pre order button.

Also for configurable products to display always an add to cart button.

Below is the code that I have been playing with, may be completely the wrong way round  it, but works for simple products. However for configurable is displaying two URL's as it's calling a string twice.

If anyone could simply modify the code it so it works correctly that would be great!

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
       <a href="#" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><img src="<?PHP
        $str = $this->getSkinUrl('images/btn_add_to_cart.gif');
        $stre = $this->getSkinUrl('images/pre-order.gif');
if ($_product->isConfigurable()) 
{print "str";} ?>


<?PHP if ((int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()> 0) 
{print "$str";
}
else 
{print "$stre";}?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>";}?>
</a> 
            <?php else: ?>

    <div class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>')"><img
    <?php if ($_product->isConfigurable()
           || 0 < (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()): ?>
        src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/btn_add_to_cart.gif'); ?>"
    <?php else: ?>
        src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pre-order.gif'); ?>"
    <?php endif; ?>
        alt="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>"
        title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>" /></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel like this answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.